# Run an android application within my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to run an application inside a panel in my application window or show the application inside a surface in my application.

How can I do that ? Could you give me an example?

Thank you

Comment: You can't do that.  Not possible.

Comment: Nope (as Simon says).  Android is very different from other OS's.